# nodejs, function jumping to a completely unrelated line for no reason?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to add a command to an already existing project [InsomBot](https://github.com/brewcauldron/InsomBot) to retrieve a League of Legends player's information, I am using [lol-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lol-api) found on npm for this, the only modifications made to this package were to update the API url's as they were outdated and incorrect, my code is below and an image of the issue in a debugger is also below, once the program reaches line 105 it jumps to line 111 for seemingly no reason, perhaps I'm missing a simple indentation error here or I'm not closing something properly, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

i.stack.imgur.com/PnDHU.png (Seems I can't post more than 2 links)

```
var cc = require('config-multipaas'),
  env = require('./env.json'),
  Discord = require('discord.js'),
  Imgur = require("imgur-search"),
  Giphy = require('giphy-wrapper')(env["giphy_key"]),
  urban = require('urban'),
  api = require('lol-api');


//lol
api.configure("API_KEY_HIDDEN");


var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

var config_overrides = {
  PORT: server_port
}
var config = cc(config_overrides);

var mybot = new Discord.Client();
var isearch = new Imgur(env["imgur_key"]);

var termCount = new Map();
var seenURLs = new Map();

mybot.on("message", function (msg) {

  var message = msg.content;

  //keywords
  var giphy = "/giphy ";
  var imgurKey = "/img ";
  var hatter = "hater";
  var def = "/define ";
  var commands = "/commands";
  var lolstatus = "/lolstatus";

  // Reply to direct mentions
  if (msg.isMentioned(mybot.user)) {
    mybot.reply(msg, "right back atcha");
    return;
  }

  // Giphy
  var giphyIndex = message.indexOf(giphy);
  if (giphyIndex > -1) {
    var term = message.substring(giphyIndex + giphy.length).trim().replace(/\s/g, "+");

    var count = termCount.get(term) || 0;
    // console.log("count for term " + term + " is: " + count);
    termCount.set(term,count+1);

    Giphy.search(term, 100, count, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }

      var items = data.data;
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length / 2.0);

      // console.log("found " + items.length + " items for " + term);
      while (index < items.length && seenURLs.get(items[index].url) !== undefined) {
        index++;
      }
      // console.log("using? result number " + index);

      if (items.length > index) {
        var item = items[index];
        seenURLs.set(item.url, 1);
        mybot.sendMessage(msg, item.url);
      } else {
        var apology = "sorry, I couldn't find any giphys for the term: " + term;
        mybot.reply(msg, apology);
      }
    });

    return;
  }
  //Imgur
  var imgurIndex = message.indexOf(imgurKey);
  if (imgurIndex > -1) {
    var term = message.substring(imgurIndex + imgurKey.length).trim().replace(/\s/g, "+");
    // console.log("searching imgur for term: " + term);
    isearch.search(term).then(function(results) {
      // console.log("found results: " + JSON.stringify(results,null,2));
      if (results === undefined || results.length === 0) {
        mybot.reply(msg, "sorry, I couldn't find any imgurs for the term: " + term);
        return;
      }

      var image = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
      mybot.sendMessage(msg, "Here's a description of an image: " + image.title + " " + image.description + " " + image.link);
    });
    return;
  }
  //lol
  var lolIndex = message.indexOf(lolstatus);
  debugger;
  if (lolIndex > -1) {
    debugger;
    var term = message.substring(lolIndex + lolstatus.length).trim().replace(/\s/g, "+");
    debugger;
    api.summonerByName(term, 'na', function(results){
      debugger;
      console.log(results);
    });
  }
  //Define
  var defIndex = message.indexOf(def);
  if (defIndex > -1) {
    var term = message.substring(defIndex + def.length).trim().replace(/\s/g, "+");
    urban(term).first(function(json) {
      if (json !== undefined) {
        // console.log("got json from UD: " + JSON.stringify(json,null,2));
        var definition = "" + json.word + ": " + json.definition + "\nupvotes: " + json.thumbs_up + "   downvotes: " + json.thumbs_down + "\n\nExample: " + json.example;
        mybot.reply(msg, definition);
      }
      else {
        var apology = "sorry, I couldn't find a definition for: " + term;
        mybot.reply(msg, apology);
      }
    });
  }

  //Hatter
  if (message === hatter) {
    mybot.sendMessage(msg, "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CM5gg9YVAAAVMcn.png");
    return;
  }

  //Commands
  if (message === commands) {
    mybot.sendMessage(msg, "Available commands:[/] giphy | img | define");
    return;
  }

});

mybot.login(env["discord_email"], env["discord_pass"]);
```

Line 105 = api.summonerByName(term, 'na', function(results){
Line 111 = var defIndex = message.indexOf(def);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 111 contains the next statement after line 105, so it makes perfect sense.

`api.summonerByName()` is an asynchronous method, so its callback (lines 106 and 107) will be called only when there are results available, but the rest of your program will continue to run.

Comment: @user1651663 what is the actual problem?

Comment: Well, it's not running anything between lines 105 and 111... and I need it to.

Comment: @user1651663 it will run once `api.summonerByName()` has retrieved the results. I have no idea about the specifics of that method so I have no idea why it's not calling your callback function.

Comment: Thing is though, it's not? The method being used can be found here https://github.com/stumac/lol-api/blob/master/lib/lolapi.js#L61

Comment: @user1651663 that module is broken IMO. If you look [at this code](https://github.com/stumac/lol-api/blob/master/lib/lolapi.js#L96-L100), if an error occurs or the HTTP status code isn't 200, it will never call your callback. That's a bug.